# Calculating a period in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Why does this code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Period

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val p = Person("Boris",LocalDate.of(1987,1,1))
  println("Person's age is ${p.age()}")
}

class Person(val name: String, val dateOfBirth: LocalDate = LocalDate.of(1900,1,1)) {
  fun age() {
    Period.between(this.dateOfBirth,LocalDate.now()).getYears()
  }
}
```

produce this output:

```
Person's age is kotlin.Unit
```

and how do I get it to print the person's age in years instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your age function doesn't have a return type and thus displays Unit.